# send email in php with attachment

Tags: php, email

i have use this code in php mail send with attachment. I am using the Apache http server with wamp.

```
            <?php $to = 'santosh_091020@rediffmail.com';

// Declaring the necessary variables for mail sending :

                $subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
                $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
                $mob = $_REQUEST['mob'] ;
               $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'] ; 
               $message  = ' santosh enquire \n\nName: '.$name.' \n Email:'. $email.' \n Mobile:'.     $mob.' \n Message: '.$msg.' \n ';

// Declaration of the attributes for attachment.

               $upload_name=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
               $upload_type=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];
               $upload_size=$_FILES["upload"]["size"];
               $upload_temp=$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
               $fp = fopen($upload_temp, "rb");
               $file = fread($fp, $upload_size);
                fclose($fp);
              $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
              $num = md5(time());

// Defining the contents of the header.

               $headers = "From: ".$email. "\r\n" . "CC: santosh@creativecrows.com" ;

               $headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
               $headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
               $headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
               $headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

              //$headers .= "Message-ID: <".gettimeofday()."  TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
               $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";

               $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
               $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
               $headers .= "".$message."\n";
               $headers .= "--".$num."\n";

               $headers  .= "Content-Type:".$upload_type." ";
               $headers  .= "name=\"".$upload_name."\"r\n";
               $headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
               $headers  .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
               $headers  .= "filename=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\n";
               $headers  .= "".$file."\r\n";
               $headers  .= "--".$num."--"; 
              //$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

// sending the mail.

               if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
                {
               echo "Email sent";
               send();

                } 
               else
                {
               echo "Email sending failed";
                }
    //send mail in client   
               function send()
                {
               $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
               $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
               $to= trim($email);   
               $subject  = 'thanx';
               $message = '<html><head><title>HTML email</title></head>
              <body style="background-color:#000099;"><p style="color:#000099;">This email contains  HTML Tags!</p><table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td></tr></table></body></html>';$headers1 = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
               $headers1.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
               $headers1.= "From: ".$email;

               if(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers1))
                {
               echo "Email sent";
                }
               else
                {
               echo "Email sending failed";
               echo $to;
               echo $subject;
               echo $message;
                }
            }

            ?>
```

but i got the following error;

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

                 1.0@localhost

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: Domain name not found.
```

please help me. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this URL,
seems your header info is not absolute
http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = '';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = '';
$mail->FromName = '';
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email'], '');  // Add a recipient

$mail->AddReplyTo('', 'Information');
$mail->AddCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;      
                           // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/"'.$row['file1'].'"');    // Add attachments
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = '';
$mail->Body    = '<p>type whatever you want</p>';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```